# Juego.exe dejó de funcionar (convertir de .py a .exe)

Tags: python, tkinter, python-3.7, pygame

iré al grano, he intentado convertir mi juego hecho en python, usé tkinter y pygame para la interfaz gráfica, el problema es que al momento de crear el ejecutable usando "auto_py_to_exe" todo está bien, pero al abrir el archivo carga una parte y luego dice que el juego dejó de funcionar, usé Cx_Freeze y tampoco funcionó, usé pyinstaller y me aparece lo mismo cuando uso auto_py_to_exe, es decir, juego.exe dejó de funcionar. Uso la versión 3.7.4 de python.
Claramente tengo todas las carpetas que usé para el juego.
Adjunto imagen del error:
[image: Error]

Adjunto el código que utilicé con **Cx_Freeze**:

```
    import cx_Freeze

executables = [cx_Freeze.Executable("BattleShip.py")]

cx_Freeze.setup(
    name = "BattleShip",
    options = {"build_exe" : {"packages": ["pygame", "random", "sys", "os", "tkinter"], 
                            "include_files": ["jstring.py", "sound", "img"]}},
    executables = executables
)
```

**Código en Py2Exe:**

```
import os
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe
setup(console=['BattleShip.py'])
```

En los demás solo fuí a el cmd (en administrador y puse):

**PyInstall:**

```
pyinstall --onefile BattleShip.py
```

Comment: si deseas ayuda provee un [mre]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te puedo ayudar con Pyinstyaller. El problema está en --onefile. Al hacer esto le estás diciendo que meta todo el contenido (librerías, imágenes, código, etc...) embebido en un único archivo.

¿Usa imágenes tu aplicación? Pues ahí está el problema. Seguramente en tu código sigas enlazando las imágenes como si estuviesen en tu disco duro local, algo que no es verdad cuando lo conviertes en exe pues probablemente ese exe estará en otro sitio. Al no encontrarlas, da el error y finaliza.

Para comprobar que esto es cierto, abre una consola de comandos (CTRL+R, escribes "cmd" y enter) y ejecuta desde ahí tu archivo exe. Ahí podrás ver mejor cual es el error que sucede al arrancar. Otra cosa que puedes hacer es copiar la carpeta de imágenes a la misma altura que el exe. Así debería funcionar ya que al no decirle nada, irá a buscarlas ahí.

Si tu problema es con las imágenes te voy a poner en el buen camino:

1. Usar el fichero spec generado la primera vez que compilaste tu código. Lo editas, añades todo lo que necesitas (sobre todo en la parte de "datas=None" que tendrás que reemplazar correctamente para que se añadan las imágenes al ejecutable). La próxima vez en lugar de usar Pyinstall con tu app.py lo haces con tu app.spec.

[Using Spec Files](https://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/spec-files.html)

2. Seguir las instrucciones que se detallan cláramente en la respuesta elegida [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58184903/pyinstaller-embed-images-folder-in-onefile-windowed-application)

Un saludo.